# have two Visual Studio code windows running react but on different ports

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

As the question state.
I simply don't want to close the Terminal in one Visual Studio Code window to be able to
debug another Visual Studio Code window with React. Change the ports in npm something but I have search but cant find anything on this

Answer (score 1):

you can modified package.json in scripts.
default -> "start": "react-scripts start",
and you can add with PORT like -> "start": "PORT=4000 react-scripts start" (ex: i use port 4000)

and you can update to another your project react. when you run react development together, and now, your port in the project react is safe, not conflicts.

Comment: Thanks also for pc it's  `"set PORT=3034&& react-scripts start",`

Comment: Actually it's not working if the two projects use the same browser like Chrome

Comment: Any ide unable to attach project 2 to browser if browser have a debug session from the first project